html как использовать сторонии js скрипты и require
У меня есть html код с двумя кнопками и два js файла.
Одна кнопка конект
Другай дисконект
Один скрипт конектится к нужному мне ресурсу а второй должен дисконектиться
Но как мне во второй js файл передать нужную переменную с конектом?

Через глобальную переменную, если 2 js подключены к одному html и не перегружается страница. Либо через localStorage. А так, покажите ваш код, чтт бы можно было дать более объективный ответ

Да, спасибо большое действительно помогло. А ты случаем не подскажешь как использовать require в коде? Мне через сайт нужно запустить бота для майкрафт. Но что бы это сделать нужно загрузить библиотеку весь день пытаюсь. Ничего не нашел

Require в html работать не будет. Нужен сборщик. Либо посмотреть нужную либу на cdn и если есть, просто подключить к странице

Можно более подробно и по возможно если есть статью?

Все зависит от того, что вы делаете, что за библиотека и т.д. Может это серверная библиотека и на клиенте она работать не сможет

Я использую electron для деск топного приложения. И мне нужно подключить клиентскую библиотеку это возможно сделать?

С electron не рвботал, тонкостей не знаю. Советую вам отредактировать вопрос и добавить в него все эти подробности, что выяснили. В теги добавить электрон, в сам вопрос подробно описать, что и зачем делаете, какую библиотеку хотите использовать, ссылку на доку к этой либе, ваш код, как пытались сделать, ошибки, которые при этом возникали
